# How to update struct field spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a struct as part of my **json**.

`store: struct (c1, c2, c3, c4)`

I would like to update `c2` in place so no new field is created. After update it should be same struct with new value for `c2`.

In **spark/scala**, I have already tried:

```
df.withColumn("store.c2", newVal)
```

But this creates a new field `store.c2`,
Columns not part of struct, I am able to update.

```
df.withColumn("columnTen", newValue)
```

does not create new field and updated to `newValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a new structtype based on an existing schema by using the following:

```
val newstructtype = StructType(existing_df.schema.map( x => {
if (x.name == "fieldname_to_change") StructField("new_fieldname",TimestampType,true)
else x})
```

Answer (score 5):

doing this

```
df.withColumn("store",struct($"store.c1", $"store.c2", $"store.c3", lit(newValue) as "c4"))
```

will replace the value in the `store.c4` field.

Answer (score 5):

Since Spark 3.1+, you can use [`withField`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#withField(fieldName:String,col:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) on a struct column:

> An expression that adds/replaces field in `StructType` by name.

```scala
df.withColumn("store", $"store".withField("c2", lit(newVal)))
```