# Remove or Replace a value in Struct column in Pyspark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, parsing, pyspark

I have a struct column in pyspark with below schema:

```
root
 |-- transformedJSON: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _class: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- $oid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- password: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- token: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- token_expire_in: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- token_generation: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Op: string (nullable = true)
```

And the data looks something like this:
[image]

The token key value is not parsed correctly because it contains `\`
Now I want to remove the `\` from only the `token` but cannot figure out how to do so.
Only thing I found was to use withColumn with `regex_replace` but it looks for the whole column values and I want to filter out to the field inside the struct column

```
object
_class: null
_id: {"$oid": "6090c1566264e14261d02c23"}
email: "sandra@arias.com"
password: "2Qu3qe/f"
token: "{\"refresh_token\":\"8rR6mOQhDBSmg1S6sfEP1dYGzYGOlffrgop0OcCL\",\"token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"expires_in\":43200,\"access_token\":\"KWVyQME7bsuCpVgEJfuzjsCHphGkfexrZyB9w5Xc\"}"
token_expire_in: "1620178814909"
token_generation: "1620139214909"
uid: "81YoCIzxHRQJesGdvnEPfC5NdXr2"
```

Comment: Please add some example input json data as text (that can be copied). This helps reviewers in not having to create it themselves to supply you with a solution :)

Comment: @Koedlt added the data

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886708/how-to-update-struct-field-spark-scala

Answer (score 0):

You can read or parse the json string to the struct column as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, IntegerType

df = spark.read.json('test.json')

token_schema = StructType() \
    .add("refresh_token", StringType(), True) \
    .add("token_type", StringType(), True) \
    .add("expires_in", IntegerType(), True) \
    .add("access_token", StringType(), True)

df = df.withColumn("token", f.from_json("token", schema=token_schema))
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)


root
 |-- _class: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- $oid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |-- password: string (nullable = true)
 |-- token: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- refresh_token: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- token_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- expires_in: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- access_token: string (nullable = true)
 |-- token_expire_in: string (nullable = true)
 |-- token_generation: string (nullable = true)
 |-- uid: string (nullable = true)

+------+--------------------------+----------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+----------------------------+
|_class|_id                       |email           |password|token                                                                                              |token_expire_in|token_generation|uid                         |
+------+--------------------------+----------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+----------------------------+
|null  |{6090c1566264e14261d02c23}|sandra@arias.com|2Qu3qe/f|{8rR6mOQhDBSmg1S6sfEP1dYGzYGOlffrgop0OcCL, Bearer, 43200, KWVyQME7bsuCpVgEJfuzjsCHphGkfexrZyB9w5Xc}|1620178814909  |1620139214909   |81YoCIzxHRQJesGdvnEPfC5NdXr2|
+------+--------------------------+----------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+----------------------------+
```